# DFP Responsiveness in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, google-dfp, responsiveness, responsive-images

I just joined doubleclick for publishers and want to show responsive ad units without mapping specific sizes.

I want to apply a class like img-responsive where I fix the width and let the height adapt.

I know there are many questions but I'm looking for a solution similar to bootstrap with no mapping at all.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not practical serve ads then use CSS to make to them responsive. They are embedded in iframes which to not work well in responsive layouts because they don't resize properly out of the box. The second problem is the content of the ads is not responsive.  If you ask for an ad that is 728 x 90, it will not look right if you change the dimensions of its iframe. You would have to use Javascript and listen to resize events, then ask GPT for an ad with the appropriate dimension.  This is more work than using the built in size mapping functionality.